# Laravel how to query a pivot table created_at timestamp equal to a date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have users and habits, and a habit_user table to join them.

I am querying like this:

```
$track = $h->userAnswers()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->wherePivot('created_at', '=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i))->first();
```

This is running in a loop that is counting back for 7 days.  there is a record in the db that is created_at: 2018-10-23 04:48:44

In my habit model I have the method you'd expect:

```
public function userAnswers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Habit', 'habit_user_answers')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('answer_one', 'created_at')->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');

}
```

Why won't query get a record?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, I think you need to consider Laravel conventions about naming methods and properties.

I'll assume the following based on your structure that includes users and habits. So, we have a `User` model and a `Habit` model, a user `belongsToMany habits` and a habit `belongsToMany users`. Also the pivot table `habit_user` contains extra fields like `answer_one`, `answer_created_at` and timestamps.

If you want now to query the habits now you have two solutions:

1- using wherePivot()

```
auth()->user()->habits()->wherePivot('answer_created_at', today())->get();
auth()->user()->habits()->wherePivot('answer_one', '!=', 'something')->get();
```

2- using whereHas()

```
auth()->user()->whereHas('habits', function($query){
    $query->where('pivot.answer_one', 'something');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the date time so only if both date and time is same, the query will throw a result.

You can compare dates like so:

```
wherePivot('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->startOfDay())->wherePivot('created_at', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->endOfDay())
```